# E: Unable to parse package

Tags: apt, updates, 14.04

When I do an apt-get update, I get this message at the end:

```
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Problem opening /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Originally, the problem referring to "Translation" wasn't showing, it was only the one referring to "AMD64 packages". So I did a little web surfing and came across a possible solution.
I did this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
```

And after than the "Translation" Errors came.

Help?